# azure web app backup not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 web applications in azure on a Standard App Service Plan (S1 Standard).
After I finish a scheduled backup configuration, it returns to the backup blade and show the following message:
"Backup and Restore feature requires your App Service plan to be Standard or higher. Click here to upgrade your App Service plan and access this feature."
Also all the backup options are grey out.

But I have a standard service plan already...

Is there other requirement that I'm missing?

Sometimes if I keep refreshing I can access the backup configuration again, but when I try to configure the backup it never finishes loading the backup options (Storage account/Schedule/Database).

Is there a problem with the backup system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a Azure Web App in South Central US location and tested its backup feature. It worked fine on my side.

> Is there other requirement that I'm missing?

No, what you did is right. The issue maybe a temporary problem of Azure backup service or caused by the cache of your browser. Please clear the cache or history of your browser and try your steps again.

Comment: Looks like it was a temporary issue, I logged in today and I can complete the configuration process and execute backups